# ElasticSearch : Failure Sink always running

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, serilog, serilog-sinks-elasticsearch

The logs are always being written to both Elastic Search and Local Log Files (when used as a Failure Sink) . This should not be the case. Local Log Files should be created only when the application fails to write logs to Elasticsearch

```
                Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(TextWriter.Synchronized(file));
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                 .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                 .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions
                 {          
                     EmitEventFailure = EmitEventFailureHandling.WriteToSelfLog |
                               EmitEventFailureHandling.WriteToFailureSink |
                               EmitEventFailureHandling.RaiseCallback,
                     FailureSink = new RollingFileSink("./failures.txt", new JsonFormatter(),null,30)
                 })
                 .CreateLogger();
```

> Error on SelfLog:
> Caught exception while preforming bulk operation to Elasticsearch: Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. Call: Status code unknown from: POST /_bulk ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Comment: did you get the solution? I am facing the same issue.